# confusion with jquery and getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

only the first alert is showing.

i have tried only one at a time and still, only if it's before the getElementById does it work...

```
$('#t').keyup(function() {

alert('1');

var a = document.getElementById('t').value;

alert(a);

}
```

Comment: What's your question? What's your html? Do you have a [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) that reproduces your problem..? And why not simply `alert($(this).val());`?

Comment: Seems to be working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/8PFzu/

Comment: One at a time? Are you saying that you have multiple elements with the same ID?

Comment: why do you need both the functions? it's mix of jquery and javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, no, both alerts are showing perfectly fine as seen in [this live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/C5Cj6/1/). And by the way if you already use jQuery in your application you shouldn't need `document.getElementById` anymore. You should use jQuery's equivalent which in this case would be the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
$('#t').keyup(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
    alert(value);
});
```

Ah and last but not least did you notice the closing `);` at the end of my code which is missing in yours?

And of course ids in HTML documents should be unique meaning that you can have only **one** element with `id="t"` in your entire page otherwise you get invalid markup.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has syntax errors in it.  Maybe it should be:

```
$('#t').keyup(function() {

  alert('1');

  var a = document.getElementById('t').value;

  alert(a);

});
```

Also you should really be able to just do:

```
$('#t').keyup(function() {

  alert('1');

  var a = $(this).val();

  alert(a);

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is missing a closing `);`.  You should not be getting any alerts at all.  I would add this in and see if things start to function as expected.

If you are using jQuery I would recommend using the id selector rather than getElementById.  Making both of these changes would make your code look like this:

```
$('#t').keyup(function() {

alert('1');

var a = $(this).val(); //document.getElementById('t').value;

alert(a);

});
```

Comment: @AbeMiessler - I think he left out the sad winking face on purpose. `(;` +1